# ActionMailer without template and multipart email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, actionmailer, multipart

Rails will helpfully send multipart email if there are multiple template types present (e.g. `.txt` and `.html` files for the same mailer action).

However, what if I want to do this without templates? Normally we specify body and content_type as arguments:

```
mail to: 'a@example.com', subject: 'Hello', body: 'Hi', content_type: 'text/html'
```

So how can this be achieved with multiple bodies having their own type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class TestMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  def welcome_email
    mail(to: 'example@example.com', subject: 'Welcome to My Awesome Site') do |format|
      format.html { render html: '<h1>Welcome XYZ!</h1>'.html_safe }
      format.text { render plain: 'Welcome XYZ' }
    end
  end
end
```

To use it call: `TestMailer.welcome_email.deliver_now`.

[Documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html), section 2.4

Comment: This was working fine in Rails 4.2 and 5.0, but in 5.1 it fails with: `ActionView::MissingTemplate`. The documentation [section 2.11](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#sending-emails-without-template-rendering) explains that to send without a template, use a body: parameter in the mail() call, but it doesn't explain how to deal with multipart emails.

Comment: @Brent I checked that with Rails 5.1.5 and no exception was raised